# How to disable long press triggering right click context-menu on Gnome3.18 desktop

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome3

In Gnome3.18, a feature is introduced：

> Context menus can now be accessed using a touch screen — to activate,
>   just press and hold.

However, I would like to disable such feature on desktop. Anyway I can disable the long press feature, or even remove the context-menu?

Ref: https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.18/

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the Activities overview and start typing Universal Access.
2. Click on Universal Access to open the panel.
3. Press Click Assist in the Pointing & Clicking section.
4. Switch Simulated Secondary Click to OFF.

Found that [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-right-click.html.en).

Comment: Thanks. This was causing me to randomly place blocks in minecraft :P